# Status message handling in Symfony3

Tags: exception, symfony

I often find that my controllers in Symfony resemble the following:

```
try {
    $myService->doFoo();
    $success = 'Congratulations! It worked!';
} catch (ExceptionOne $e) {
    $error = 'Exception one occurred. Please try this instead.'
} catch (ExceptionTwo $e) {
    $error = 'Exception two occurred. Please try this instead.'
} catch (ExceptionThree $e) {
    $error = 'Exception three occurred. Please try this instead.'
} catch (ExceptionFour $e) {
    $error = 'Exception four occurred. Please try this instead.'
} catch (ExceptionFive $e) {
    $error = 'Exception five occurred. Please try this instead.'
} catch (ExceptionSix $e) {
    $error = 'Exception six occurred. Please try this instead.'
} catch (ExceptionSeven $e) {
    $error = 'Exception seven occurred. Please try this instead.'
} catch (ExceptionEight $e) {
    $error = 'Exception eight occurred. Please try this instead.'
} catch (ExceptionNine $e) {
    $error = 'Exception nine occurred. Please try this instead.'
}
return $this->render('Bundle:Foo:bar.html.twig', [
    'success' => $success,
    'error' => $error,
]);
```

Obviously this is an exaggerated scenario, but essentially I'm finding that my controllers are becoming convoluted with long error/success message logic. Does Symfony have a better approach to this pattern, in keeping with the skinny-controller paradigm?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an ExceptionListener can help you here.

From symfony [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html) :

```
class ExceptionListener
{
 public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
 {
    // You get the exception object from the received event
    $exception = $event->getException();
    $message = sprintf(
        'My Error says: %s with code: %s',
        $exception->getMessage(),
        $exception->getCode()
    );

    // Customize your response object to display the exception details
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($message);

    // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception that
    // holds status code and header details
    if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
        $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
        $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
    } else {
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    // Send the modified response object to the event
    $event->setResponse($response);
 }
}
```